# Excel named ranges to make incrementing headers and sub headers

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am creating a spreadsheet application which will require a user to fill in different sections of an input sheet. To separate out these sections into logical means, I am using headers and sub headers as seen below:

[image: Image of input sheet]

If I have a lot of headers, there will be a significant amount of manual work in numbering the headers. I have made some attempt at automating the process by creating a `Header1` named range which equates to the grey headers in the picture below. So within the `A2` and `A11` cells, the formula is `=Header1`. The formula in the `Header1` named range is:

`IF(COUNTA(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("$A$1",":",ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN()))))=0,0,INDEX(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("$A$1",":",ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN()))),MATCH(ROW(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN()))),INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("$A$1",":",ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN()))),TRUE)))+1`

Basically the formula counts all of the values in column A and adds 1 on. In other words it nicely increments every time you call `Header1` in your cell, regardless of what worksheet you are in (hence the use of `INDIRECT`). The only piece of hard coding is the starting cell which is `A1` and I have put a 0 in that so it detects to start from 1.

**My question is** - In a similar manner to how I have achieved incrementing headers using named ranges, how can I do this for sub headers? My picture above shows the effect I am trying to achieve (i.e. `2.1`, `2.2`) however I want this to be automatic by simply putting a formula of `=Header2` in the cell for example.

**EDIT** - I have gotten as far as this formula:

`=SUM(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("$A$1",":",ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN()-1)))) & "." & MAX(1,COUNTA(INDEX(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("$B$1",":",ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN()))),MATCH(SUM(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("$A$1",":",ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN()))))-1,INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("$A$1",":",ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN()-1))),FALSE)):INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN()))))`

...which works when placed as a formula in a cell, but doesn't work when used in a named range. Odd!

Comment: I think I have an approach but am not clear on exactly what you want to do.  Do you have a spreadsheet that contains a lot of data and you want to insert the headers?  Can you show a sample of your "input" sheet?  If that is not the case, please add an additional comment to more explicitly say what you want to do.

Comment: I've been more explicit. The input sheet is not relevant to the question however

Comment: It is.  What are the data?  Numerics only?  Integers?  Mixed?  A solution that overcomes your problems depends on the data.  Are you creating the header sheet before the data are loaded?  If so, the problem is easy to solve.  You have to be even more specific before help can be offered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good idea using `Defined Names` to hold the formula. However your formula is highly volatile.

Suggest to create two defined names at workbook level *(scope)* as follows:

1. Named `_Hdr` *(change as required)* with the following formula:

   ```
   =IF( COLUMN() <> 1, "", 1 
   + MAX( INDEX(!$A:$A, 1 ) : INDEX(!$A:$A, - 1 + ROW() ) ) )
   ```
2. Named `_Sub` *(change as required)* with the following formula:

   ```
   =IF( COLUMN() <> 2, "", 0.01 
   + IF( MAX( INDEX(!$A:$A, 1 ) : INDEX(!$A:$A, - 1 + ROW() ) ) 
   > MAX( INDEX(!$B:$B, 1 ) : INDEX(!$B:$B, - 1 + ROW() ) ), 
   MAX( INDEX(!$A:$A, 1 ) : INDEX(!$A:$A, - 1 + ROW() ) ), 
   MAX( INDEX(!$B:$B, 1 ) : INDEX(!$B:$B, - 1 + ROW() ) ) ) )
   ```

*Use `0.1` if sub items are less than 10, if higher but less than 100 use `0.01` (adjust as required)*

***Edit:*** Add `!` to the column ranges in the formulas to ensure that the references will automatically update to the corresponding `Sheet` where the formula is used.

*The formulas above are broken in several lines to ease reading and understanding, enter then as one line when creating the names.*

Also suggest to hide the `Define Names` *(i.e. `Visible = False`)* in order to avoid formulas being *accidentally* altered.

With the above names:

- There is no need to enter zero at row 1.
- The formulas work with numbers ignoring any labels.
- They check first that the formula is entered in the expected column *(i.e. `_Hdr` and `_Sub` columns `1` and `2` respectively)*.
- As the formulas work with numbers they get the `MAX` number for each column and add `1` or `0.1` to generate the next number.
- Formulas are no volatile *(no use of `INDIRECT`)*.
- They use the `INDEX` function to generate the required ranges.

Comment: That is exceptional. Works completly as you described. The only issue I've found is that if I am on a subheader of `1.9` the following sub header will be `2.0` as opposed to `1.10`

Comment: I see, no mention about having more that 9 sub items. But it's not a problem though. Just do this, instead of adding `0.1` add `0.01`. The first sub item should be `X.01` instead of `X.1`, update accordingly in case there are more than 99 sub items... Format your cells accordingly. If this solves your problem then please accept the answer and help us to keep the site clean. thanks...