# Using Excel to increment named ranges for headers

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is a follow on to a previous question - [Excel named ranges to make incrementing headers and sub headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34112138/excel-named-ranges-to-make-incrementing-headers-and-sub-headers/34117235#34117235).

**Context:** I have an Excel data worksheet which has `headers`, `sub headers` and `sub-sub headers` to divide sections of the sheet. To make the numbering of the headers automated (as seen in the picture below), I am utilising formulaic named ranges called `Header1`, `Header2` and `Header3` for the header, sub-header and sub-sub header respectively.

[image: Image of headered Excel worksheet]

The formula for `Header1` is:

```
=IF( COLUMN() <> 1, "", 1 + MAX( INDEX(!$A:$A, 1 ) : 
INDEX(!$A:$A, - 1 + ROW() ) ) )
```

and the formula for `Header2` is:

```
=IF( COLUMN() <> 2, "", 0.1 + IF( MAX( INDEX(!$A:$A, 1 ) : INDEX(!$A:$A, - 1 
+ ROW() ) ) > MAX( INDEX(!$B:$B, 1 ) : INDEX(!$B:$B, - 1 + ROW() ) ), 
MAX( INDEX(!$A:$A, 1 ) : INDEX(!$A:$A, - 1 + ROW() ) ), 
MAX( INDEX(!$B:$B, 1 ) : INDEX(!$B:$B, - 1 + ROW() ) ) ) )
```

*Please note I've broken the formulas over multiple lines for readability.*

**Usage:** Quite simply, I can just call `=Header1` in cells `A1` and `A20` and the headers will automatically increment. The same with `=Header2` in `B4`.

**My question:** With the formula for `Header2`, it increments up to `1.9` however the next increment point after that is `2.0` and I would like it to be `1.10` like in the picture above. How can this be achieved? Also, how would `sub-sub headers` be achieved (labelled as `Further Sub Header` in the image above)? Ideally I would like sub-sub headers to follow the convention of `1.1.10` as well.

Comment: Just so I am clear - you will be filling in the text in columns B, C and D and want automatic numbering of them using the format x.y.z yes? But you will also use those columns for formulas of indented headers , seems a bit messy to start with??

Comment: Thanks @StevenMartin. Yes your assumptions are correct and x.y.z is how I would like the sub-sub headers to be displayed but note how the sub-headers should run in to `1.9`, `1.10`, `1.11` as well. I agree it's messy in terms of implementation but from a users perspective it is immensely usable and readable

Comment: Why not follow the advice EMM gave you and increment by 0.01 ? (or 0.001 if you want more than 99 Sub-Headers)

Comment: @chrisneilsen It doesn't allow for sub-sub headers and is not as readable as proposed in my question. I think Jeeped has the most desirable solution.

Comment: @Barry, the Named Range method can be extended to Sub-Sub-Headers.  Are you interested?  And which of `1.09, 1.10` is more readable than `1.9, 1.10` is a matter of opinion

Comment: @chrisneilsen no you're right, matter of opinion purely. Very interested to see sub-sub headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sub-Header formula to allow up to 99 levels:

```
=IF( COLUMN() <> 2, "", 0.01 + 
   IF( MAX( INDEX(!$A:$A, 1 ) : INDEX(!$A:$A, - 1  + ROW() ) ) > MAX( INDEX(!$B:$B, 1 ) : INDEX(!$B:$B, - 1 + ROW() ) ),  
     MAX( INDEX(!$A:$A, 1 ) : INDEX(!$A:$A, - 1 + ROW() ) ),  
     MAX( INDEX(!$B:$B, 1 ) : INDEX(!$B:$B, - 1 + ROW() ) ) ) )
```

Sub-Sub Header formula

```
=IF( COLUMN() <> 3, "", 0.0001 + 
   IF( MAX( INDEX(!$B:$B, 1 ) : INDEX(!$B:$B, - 1  + ROW() ) ) > MAX( INDEX(!$C:$C, 1 ) : INDEX(!$C:$C, - 1 + ROW() ) ),  
     MAX( INDEX(!$B:$B, 1 ) : INDEX(!$B:$B, - 1 + ROW() ) ),  
     MAX( INDEX(!$C:$C, 1 ) : INDEX(!$C:$C, - 1 + ROW() ) ) ) )
```

And for the magic part, apply numeric format to column `C` of `0.00.00`

---

Suplimentary answer, a general form of  Named Range formula that returns a header value dependant on the Column it's entered in.

Use a single Named Range formula eg `Header`

It will return a header as follows

- Column A: Header, (Format `0`)
- Column B: Sub-Header (Format `0.00`)
- Column C: Sub-Sub-Header (Format (`0.00.00`)
- Column D: Sub-Sub-Sub-Header (Format `0.00.00.00`)
- etc

Format as many columns as required, as indicated above

```
=IF(COLUMN()=1, MAX( INDEX(!$A:$A, 1 ) : INDEX(!$A:$A, - 1 + ROW() )) + 1,     
   IF( MAX(INDEX(!$1:$1,COLUMN()-1):INDEX(!$A:$A, ROW()-1)) > MAX(INDEX(!$1:$1,COLUMN()):INDEX(!$A:$A, ROW()-1)),       
     MAX(INDEX(!$1:$1,COLUMN()-1):INDEX(!$A:$A, ROW()-1)) + 1/10^(2*(COLUMN()-2)),       
     MAX(INDEX(!$1:$1,COLUMN())  :INDEX(!$A:$A, ROW()-1)) + 1/10^(2*(COLUMN()-1))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider a fairly simple User Defined Function (aka **UDF**) to accomplish this.

```
Function hdr_LVL()
    Application.Volatile
    Dim sLVL As String, tmp As String

    With Application.Caller
        If .Row = 1 Then
            sLVL = "1"
        ElseIf .Column = 1 Then
            sLVL = CStr(Application.CountIf(.Parent.Cells(1, .Column).Resize(.Row - 1, 1), "*") + 1)
        Else
            tmp = Application.Index(.Parent.Columns(.Column - 1), _
                        Application.Match("žžž", .Parent.Cells(1, .Column - 1).Cells.Resize(.Row - 1, 1)))
            sLVL = tmp & Chr(46) & Application.CountIf(.Parent.Cells(1, .Column).Resize(.Row - 1, 1), _
                                            tmp & Chr(42)) + 1
        End If
    End With

    hdr_LVL = sLVL
End Function
```

Granted the workbook will have to be macro-enabled or binary but I would gladly trade that to having **Circular References** sitting in my status bar all day long.

[image: hdr_lvl]

With minor restrictions following the hierarchical pattern you can just put the UDF in any cell you want. Please note that all references returned by the UDF are text strings in nature.

Comment: This is a really nice UDF, however I've seen it done with named ranges before and no circular references.

Regarding your UDF. If I start my headers 8 rows down, instead of on row 1, it seems to breakdown

Comment: Hmmm. I just cleared rows 1:6 and everything renumbered happily. btw, I had a couple versions of this going and originally posted the wrong one. The correct one is in the thread now.

Comment: Ahhh. What about if some data does exist in row 1:6 say a title or date. That appears to be throwing it. I tried changing `If .Row = 1` to `If .Row = 8` (my header starts on row 8) and it works until I get down to the next header

Comment: Yes, I guess that ultimately anyone could keep coming up with conditions where it doesn't work. I would suppose its universality will depend on how much time you wanted to spend dealing with every possible situation.

Comment: Well in this circumstance, row 8 is the row I've settled on.

Comment: You should just be able to type or 'seed' the first number in but it has to be in text form so type `'1` to get a text representation of the number 1 in A8. Actually, you can restart the numbering pretty much anywhere.